# DataGrid и ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wpf, binding, xaml

DataGrid привязан к данным следующим образом 
xaml:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
```

c#:

```
<ObservableCollection<Docs> docs = new ObservableCollection<Docs>(context.Docs);
```

Однако, изменения, сделанные в коде, не отображаются в DataGrid.

---

Чтение форумов показало, что ObservableCollection не оповещает об изменениях в элементах коллекции, а только о добавлении/удалении этих элементов. Какой выход? Писать обертку и реализовывать для нее INotifyPropertyChanged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

context.Docs.Local - биндь к гриду

подробнее здесь
http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/gg696248%28v=vs.113%29.aspx

и на сколько поммню у Grid надо вызвать, Items.Refresh() после изменений

Answer (score 1):

И так. Проблему свою я решил... Я открыл сгенерированный класс Doc и реализовал в нем INotifyPropertyChanged для поля. Скорее всего, это не идельное решение, и я опасаюсь, что если я сделаю обновление из базы данных, то этот код перезапишется. Как сделать правильнее? Можно ли сделать как-то универсальнее, для всех полей класса?

Comment: Благодарю, так будет проще.

Comment: Вообще-то вы правильно мыслите. Кошернее сделать для каждого класса во `view` его `ViewModel`.

Обновлять грид после изменения данных - лишняя связность и нарушение mvvm